# How to select rows from dataframe based on regex of multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to select rows from a dataframe `df` where a string value is not in either column `col1` or `col2`.

I can only do the following on one column:

```
df_clean = df[df["col1"].str.contains('thisstring|thatstring', na=False, case=False)==False]
```

But it would be better if I could do:

```
df_clean = df[df["col1","col2"].str.contains('thisstring|thatstring', na=False, case=False)==False]
```

Is it possible? Otherwise, I'm having to use `df_clean` from the top code and run it again for `col2` and saving into another variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['thisstring dd','thisstring ff','ee'],
                   'col2':['s thatstring','ddd','sds']})
```

If need apply `.str` function to `DataFrame`, use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for `boolean DataFrame` with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for check at least one `True` per row:

```
f = lambda x: x.str.contains('thisstring|thatstring', na=False, case=False)
df_clean = df[~df[["col1","col2"]].apply(f).any(axis=1)]
print (df_clean)
  col1 col2
2   ee  sds
```

Simpliest is add one column to another and instead compare by `False` use `~` for inverse boolean mask:

```
s = df["col1"] + ' ' + df["col2"]
df_clean = df[~s.str.contains('thisstring|thatstring', na=False, case=False)]
print (df_clean)
  col1 col2
2   ee  sds
```